# Sed - Invalid preceding regular expression

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a problem with sed code.
I wan't to do here:

From

```
uri.csv
/path/file.jpg
/path/file2.bmp
```

To

```
/path/*.jpg
/path/*.bmp
```

I'm use this code because I view the error with sed.

```
sed -r 's/(.+\/).+?(?=\.)(.+)/\\1*\\2/g' uri.csv
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Can you help me?

Comment: No look around with sed

Comment: ...and no non-greedy matching as in `.+?`.

Answer (score 2):

Lookarounds are not supported by POSIX ERE that you are using (enabled with `-r` option).

Your regex matches one or more chars, as many as possible, up to  `/` (with `(.+\/)`), then 1+ chars as few as possible are matched with `.+?`, then `(?=\.)` just requires a `.` to appear immediately on the right, and `(.+)` captures into Group 2 any 1+ chars as many as possible.

You may use

```
sed -r 's,(.*/)?.*\.,\1*.,' uri.csv
```

Or, with `-E` option:

```
sed -E 's,(.*/)?.*\.,\1*.,' uri.csv
```

Or using POSIX BRE:

```
sed 's@\(.*/\)\{0,1\}.*\.@\1*.@' uri.csv
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/w57ahM).

NOTE: When using `,` as delimiters, there is no need to escape `/` chars.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. But when I have this case: /nata.bmp, the script returned /nata.bmp and not /*.bmp. Do you have a suggestion? :)

Comment: But on this case, the script not work: /etc/content/stamp.03.17.png because the result is /etc/content/*.03.17.png. Do you have a suggestion? :)

Comment: @SavioZ Replace `[^.]*` with `.*`, see https://ideone.com/9PygaK. You would have  got the correct solution from the start had you specified the exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [Look Around](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) with sed. Better use a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner :

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.+\/).+?(?=\.)(.+)/$1*$2/g' file
/etc/designs/smartpos/images/*.svg
/etc/designs/smartpos/images/*.svg
```